# Mocking a module level function in pytest

Tags: python, module, mocking, pytest, decorator

I have a function that has a decorator. The decorator accepts arguments and the value of the argument is derived from another function call.

example.py

```
from cachetools import cached
from cachetools import TTLCache

from other import get_value


@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1, ttl=get_value('cache_ttl')))
def my_func():
    return 'result'
```

other.py

```
def get_value(key):
    data = {
        'cache_ttl': 10,
    }
    # Let's assume here we launch a shuttle to the space too.
    return data[key]
```

I'd like to mock the call to `get_value()`. I'm using the following in my test:

example_test.py

```
import mock
import pytest

from example import my_func


@pytest.fixture
def mock_get_value():
    with mock.patch(
        "example.get_value",
        autospec=True,
    ) as _mock:
        yield _mock


def test_my_func(mock_get_value):
    assert my_func() == 'result'
```

Here I'm injecting `mock_get_value` to test_my_func. However, since my decorator is called on the first import, `get_value()` gets called immediately. Any idea if there's a way to mock the call to `get_value()` before module is imported right away using pytest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `from example import my_func` inside your `with` in your test function. Also patch it where it's really coming from, `other.get_value`. That may be all it takes.

---

Python caches modules in `sys.modules`, so module-level code (like function definitions) only runs on the *first* import from *anywhere*. If this isn't the first time, you can force a re-import using either `importlib.reload()` or by deleting the appropriate key in `sys.modules` and importing again.

Beware that re-importing a module may have side effects, and you may also want to re-import the module again after running the test to avoid interfering with other tests. If another module was using objects defined in the re-imported module, these don't just disappear, and may not be updated the way it expects. For example, re-importing a module may create a second instance of what was supposed to be a singleton.

One more robust approach would be save the original imported module object somewhere else, delete from `sys.modules`, re-import with the patched version for the duration of the test, and then put back the original import into `sys.modules` after the test. You could do this with an import inside of a `patch.dict()` context on `sys.modules`.

```
import mock
import sys

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def mock_get_value():
    with mock.patch(
        "other.get_value",
        autospec=True,
    ) as _mock, mock.patch.dict("sys.modules"):
        sys.modules.pop("example", None)
        yield _mock


def test_my_func(mock_get_value):
    from example import my_func
    assert my_func() == 'result'
```

---

Another possibility is to call the decorator yourself in the test, on the original function. *If* the decorator used `functools.wraps()`/`functools.update_wrapper()`, then the original function should be available as a `__wrapped__` attribute. This may not be available depending on how the decorator was implemented.